# Error with dynamic memory

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, resize

I am trying to use the **dynamic memory method instead of the vector** method to add elements. Initially, the maximum size of the dynamic memory is set to 5. However, as soon as I try to increase more than the capacity of the current the dynamic memory, the elements of the 0th or 1st index loss their references.
The program works fine if I do not specify the size of the dynamic memory,
like: `dynamic_memory = new int`;. I am wondering why they lose their references
with the resize of the dynamic memory to more than the initial capacity.
PS: I am using **Code::Block 16.01**

Here is my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class DynamicVector
{
    public:
        DynamicVector();
        virtual ~DynamicVector();
        void insertElement(int input);
        int showCapacity();
        int showSize();
        void doubleSize(int * dynamic_memory);
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& outs, const DynamicVector obj);

    private:
        int * dynamic_memory;
        int max_count; // this is similar to the capacity of the vector
        int current_count; // this is similar to size of a vector
};

DynamicVector::DynamicVector()
{
    max_count = 5;
    dynamic_memory = new int[max_count];
    current_count = 0;
}

DynamicVector::~DynamicVector()
{
    delete [] dynamic_memory;
}

int DynamicVector::showCapacity(){
    return max_count;
}

void DynamicVector::insertElement(int input)
{
    if (current_count >= max_count)
        doubleSize(dynamic_memory);

    dynamic_memory[current_count] = input;
    current_count++;
}

void DynamicVector::doubleSize(int * dynamic_memory){
    int * tmp = new int[max_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < max_count; i++)
        tmp[i] = dynamic_memory[i];

    delete [] dynamic_memory;

    max_count = max_count * 2;

    dynamic_memory = new int[max_count];

    for (int i = 0; i < max_count; i++)
        dynamic_memory[i] = tmp[i];

    delete [] tmp;
}

int DynamicVector::showSize(){
    return current_count;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const DynamicVector obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.current_count; i++)
        outs << obj.dynamic_memory[i] << endl;
    return outs;
}

int main()
{
    DynamicVector v;
    int numberOfIntendedElement = 11;
    cout << "Previously, the capacity of vector was: " << v.showCapacity() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIntendedElement; i++)
        v.insertElement(i);

    cout << "The capacity of the new vector is: " << v.showCapacity() << endl;
    cout << "The size of the new vector is: " << v.showSize() << endl;
    cout << "The values in the dynamic vector are: \n" << v << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
41107976
42075512
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: _The program works fine if I do not specify the size of the dynamic memory, like: dynamic_memory = new int;._ What?

Comment: Instead of `new int[n]` you should be doing `std::vector<int>` which will manage memory for you far more effectively.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < max_count; i++)
        dynamic_memory[i] = tmp[i];` there are not max_cout elements in tmp. Why do you copy twice? Allocate new memory and copy the old contents.

Comment: `DynamicVector::doubleSize` is needlessly complex. Make `tmp` double the size of `max_count`, copy `dynamic_memory` into `tmp`, delete `dynamic_memory` and then set `dynamic_memory = tmp;`

Comment: Undefined behaviour here: `for (int i = 0; i < max_count; i++) dynamic_memory[i] = tmp[i];`. `tmp` has `max_count/2` elements.  This is resolved by simplifying as per above comment.

Comment: In the method Dynamic::doubleSize(int*), the second for loop should not go to max_count, it should go only upto (max_count/2 + max_count%2) because you multipliate max_count by 2.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
void doubleSize(int * dynamic_memory);
```

the `dynamic_memory` defined here shadows the member `dynamic_memory;` for comedic hi-jinks and undefined behaviour.

The local `dynamic_memory` is re-pointed at the new buffer, but the member `dynamic_memory` continues to point at the deleted original address after the function exits. This means that all subsequent inserts go into invalid memory, and Crom only knows what will happen after that.

Solution

Pass in nothing and use the member variable. Redefine the function as

```
void doubleSize();
```

Other problems are addressed in the comments and need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you all** for your valuable comments and suggestions, especially user4581301 for pointing a comedic hijinks and undefined behavior. After I redefined the function as `void doubleSize()`, it worked fine. Here is my final working code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class DynamicVector
{
    public:
        DynamicVector();
        virtual ~DynamicVector();
        void insertElement(int input);
        int showCapacity();
        int showSize();
        void doubleSize();
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& outs, const DynamicVector obj);

    private:
        int * dynamic_memory;
        int max_count; // this is similar to the capacity of the vector
        int current_count; // this is similar to size of a vector
};

DynamicVector::DynamicVector()
{
    max_count = 5;
    dynamic_memory = new int[max_count];
    current_count = 0;
}

DynamicVector::~DynamicVector()
{
    delete [] dynamic_memory;
}

int DynamicVector::showCapacity(){
    return max_count;
}

void DynamicVector::insertElement(int input)
{
    if (current_count >= max_count)
        doubleSize();

    dynamic_memory[current_count] = input;
    current_count++;
}

void DynamicVector::doubleSize(){
    int * tmp = new int[max_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < max_count; i++)
        tmp[i] = dynamic_memory[i];

    delete [] dynamic_memory;

    max_count = max_count * 2;

    dynamic_memory = new int[max_count];

    for (int i = 0; i < max_count/2; i++)
        dynamic_memory[i] = tmp[i];

    delete [] tmp;
}

int DynamicVector::showSize(){
    return current_count;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const DynamicVector obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.current_count; i++)
        outs << obj.dynamic_memory[i] << endl;
    return outs;
}

int main()
{
    DynamicVector v;
    int numberOfIntendedElement = 11;
    cout << "Previously, the capacity of vector was: " << v.showCapacity() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIntendedElement; i++)
        v.insertElement(i);

    cout << "The capacity of the new vector is: " << v.showCapacity() << endl;
    cout << "The size of the new vector is: " << v.showSize() << endl;
    cout << "The values in the dynamic vector are: \n" << v << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Previously, the capacity of vector was: 5
The capacity of the new vector is: 20
The size of the new vector is: 11
The values in the dynamic vector are:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```